# Slicing table data based on days

Tags: sql

Having the following data table:

| col1 | days |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 5 |
| D | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 7 |
| A | 4 |

I want to transform it into:

| col1 | <=2days | <=5days | <=7days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I used the below query to achieve this:

```
select col1, 
       CASE WHEN days <=2 then count(days) as "<=2days",
       CASE WHEN days > 2 and days <=5 then count(days) as "<=5days",
       CASE WHEN days > 5 and days <=7 then count(days) as "<=7days"
from tableA group by col1,days
```

But it returns a result like the following:

| col1 | <=2days | <=5days | <=7days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Can someone please help here?

Comment: Common PIVOT (search). Use conditional aggregation then transform.

Comment: PS. The output does not match the header. `'A'` have 3 values which matches the condition `<=5days`. You'd use `from 3 to 5` (for example) column header instead..

Comment: Kindly, tag only the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT col1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN days<=2 THEN 1 END) AS '<=2days',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN days<=5 and days>2 THEN 1 END) AS '<=5days',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN days<=7 and days>5 THEN 1 END) AS '<=7days'
FROM tableA
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col1
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0oinsNHW) on MySQL.